# "I tried to make an order but couldn't pay because you*had not accepted paypal payment yet."

Tags: difference, past-vs-past-perfect

> I tried to make an order but couldn't pay because you **had not accepted** paypal payment yet.

Will it be ok to use the present perfect or past simple. Is it possible to use yet with past simple?

> I tried to make an order but couldn't pay because you **did not accept** paypal payment yet.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to express with this sentence. When did this happen? Do the company accept PayPal now?

Also, what is the purpose of this observation - do you want the company to adopt PayPal as a method of payment? They do not have your money so I don't imagine that you are asking for a refund.

Please explain the circumstances. What is going on? What do you wish to happen?

Comment: Do you mean to say, "I tried to pay for my order, but couldn't because you don't (currently) accept paypal"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the past simple or the present perfect fit in this example with yet](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/273574/can-the-past-simple-or-the-present-perfect-fit-in-this-example-with-yet)